# Cannot run Citrix SchemaPrep

Tags: citrix

I'm in the process of setting upa  new XCtrix XebApp (v5.0) fram on a Win2k8 Server nd I've run into a roadblock while trying to install the Password Manager.  During the configuration discovery procees I'm required to run a Citrix SchemaPrep and a Citrix DomaninPrep script.  However, they both fail every time I run them.  I've cheked my domain controllers for errant metadeta using the NTDSUTIL tool and all seems to be correct.  All other componehts of the XenApp Server are running normally.  Any suggestions as to hwo I can get these scripts to run?

Comment: yes.  I am logged in as the dopmain admin.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the writes to make Schema changes?  You need to be a Schema administrator.

Comment: And by that Mojeska means your domain admin account needs be a member of the Schema Administrators group. Don't forget to take to remove that group membership afterwards as well.